# Display file properties dialog / Unexpected Qt warning without using Qt

Tags: qt, winapi, vbscript, windows-10, windows-scripting

Trying to display a file properties dialog programmatically in Windows 10, I first tried specifying the "properties" verb in a call to `ShellExecute` from VBScript. This produced a baffling warning:

> ```
> Qt: Untested Windows version 10.0 detected!
> ```

I haven't installed Qt on this machine, and this is produced from somewhere in the innards of the Windows script support and/or even the API level, where evidently there is a Qt hook installed.

Next, I tried another angle, using the `Shell` scripting object to invoke the "properties" verb. No `ShellExecute` here. But same result, except that now it also happens (not entirely reproducable) that I get this error box:

[image]

Code:

```vb
option explicit
dim fs: set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sub writeline( s )
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine s
end sub

dim fArg: fArg = WScript.Arguments.Item( 0 )
dim itemPath: itemPath = fs.GetAbsolutePathName( fArg )
dim itemFolderPath: itemfolderpath = fs.GetParentFolderName( itemPath )
dim itemName: itemName = fs.GetFileName( itemPath )
writeline itemPath
writeline itemFolderPath
writeline itemName

dim winShell: set winShell = CreateObject( "Shell.Application" )
dim folder: set folder = winShell.NameSpace( itemFolderPath )
writeline "Folder title: " & folder.title
dim item: set item = folder.Items.Item( itemName )
writeline "Item name: " & item.Name
dim verbs: set verbs = item.Verbs          ' !Produces Qt warning.
writeline "--------------------------------------------"
writeline verbs.Count & " verbs:"
dim propertiesVerb : set propertiesVerb = Nothing
dim verb: dim verbName
for each verb in verbs
    verbName = verb.Name
    writeline "  -> " & verb.Name
    if UCase( Replace( verbName, "&", "" ) ) = "PROPERTIES" then
        set propertiesVerb = verb
    end if
next
if propertiesVerb is Nothing then
    writeline "!Properties verb not found"
else
    writeline "Displaying properties dialog..."
    propertiesVerb.DoIt
end if
```

The baffling Qt warning, indicating a Qt hook somewhere in Windows, is produced by the so commented line, which just invokes the `Verbs` property on a folder item (scripting object).

I want to do this, display the properties dialog for a specified file, entirely in scripting, not at the Windows API level via e.g. C++ or C# which I suspect would just work.

---

**Update:**

By just adding

```vb
WScript.Sleep 200
```

after the invocation of the verb item, the dialog now shows. However, the Qt warning is there still. I don't want that.

Comment: If some kind soul could fix the syntax highlighting here I would be grateful. I tried the manual overrides specified in [the syntax highlighting FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184108/what-is-syntax-highlighting-and-how-does-it-work). They didn't work.

Comment: I've confirmed that displaying the dialog works at the API level via C++. Just two undocumented things to beware of: include option `SEE_MASK_INVOKEIDLIST` to `ShellExecuteEx`, and add a delay of at least 10 milliseconds after (I use 100 for good measure), to have the dialog show up. The latter sounds like some threading issue in the API, so it's probably not 100% reliable. But I want this cleanly from the script level, not C++.

Comment: Probably some Shell Extension you installed. To get rid of the warning you need to uninstall it.

Comment: @IInspectable: Thanks, but I haven't directly installed any such. Maybe Visual Studio has done so for me? I landed on the "solution" (read: chewing gum & duct tape kludge) of just redirecting stderr to nul.